# Linking a small image to a bigger image in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

What I want to achieve is a pop up, when a smaller version of an image is clicked, the larger version should show.

I know I will need jQuery lightbox to do this, but how do I link the small image to the bigger image in CakePHP?

I am using CakePHP 2.x - below is my code, but it is not working

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image($proposal['Proposal']['supportedfileone'],array('width'=>'200','height'=>'100')), $this->Html->image($proposal['Proposal']['supportedfileone']));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second image (the real size one), you shouldn't use the Html->image, you don't want to display it, you just have to give the path of the image, for the link.
Don't forget to turn off character escaping in the link in order to display correctly your miniature.

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image(
        $proposal['Proposal']['supportedfileone'],
        array(
            'width'=>'200',
            'height'=>'100')),
    $proposal['Proposal']['supportedfileone'],
    array(
        'data-lightbox'=>'unique_name',
        'escape' => false));
```

This should do it!